# User.Identity.Groups is not showing all users groups

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, windows-identity

I'm using `Windows.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity` for role based security in a MVC app. Recently we got new Windows 2012 domain controllers and now only the basic Windows groups are showing up under `User.Identity.Groups` in the MVC app. I'm not seeing any of the Sids of the groups I'm looking for with `User.IsInRole`

I'm wondering what's the issue here? Where do I look? Is there a way I can test if the new domain controller is propagating the groups? I'm using .Net 4.5 so, we're pretty up to date on the .Net side.

Comment: Google role-based vs action-based security